# How to get http.ResponseWriter and http.Request in Revel controller

Tags: go, revel

I am trying to implement an oauth server and the package I am using needs the complete http.ResponseWriter and http.Request types.

c.Response does not contain all the methods that http.ResponseWriter does and c.Request gives error incompatible type.

How do I get http.ResponseWriter and http.Request in a Revel controller?

```
type client struct {
    ClientId string
    ClientSecret string
}
type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c App) TokenRequest() {

    r := c.Request
    w := c.Response

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))

    var cli client
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &cli)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(cli.ClientId)

    err = OauthSrv.HandleTokenRequest(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Warning

I am generally not fond of frameworks like Revel in Go, for reasons that I hope demonstrate themselves on this page. My first recommendation would be that you examine closely what you are actually getting out of Revel that merits the use of such a heavy abstraction layer, and if it's really that valuable, you may want to ask questions going in the other direction, such as how one might make `OauthSrv` work within Revel's customized ecosystem.

### Using a Revel controller as a ResponseWriter

For something to be an `http.ResponseWriter`, it just needs to have [these methods](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).

#### Header

You need a method named `Header()` that returns an `http.Header`, which you can build out of any `map[string][]string`. Revel provides similar functionality, but through several layers of abstraction. You will need to unravel them:

1. `c.Response` is a `*Response`, so it has a field named `Out` containing an `OutResponse`.
2. An `OutResponse` has a `Header()` method—but it doesn't return an `http.Header`. Instead, it returns a `*RevelHeader`.
3. A `*RevelHeader` has a `GetAll(key string) []string` method—which is very similar to the API already provided by the built-in `map` type, but isn't exactly the same. So, you will need to copy the returned values into a new map every time `Header()` is called, in order to fully satisfy the function signature requirements.
4. Also, `GetAll()` requires you to know the key name you are interested in, and `*RevelHeader` on its own does not provide a way to look up which keys are available. *For now* we can rely on the fact that [the current implementation](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/revel/revel/-/blob/http.go#L64:6&tab=references) only has one field, a `ServerHeader` that *does* provide a `GetKeys() []string` method.

Putting all this together, we can build our `Header` method:

```
func (rrw RevelResponseWrapper) Header() http.Header {
  revelHeader := rrw.Response.Out.Header()
  keys := revelHeader.Server.GetKeys()
  headerMap := make(map[string][]string)

  for _, key := range keys {
    headerMap[key] = revelHeader.GetAll(key)
  }
  return http.Header(headerMap)
}
```

#### Write and WriteHeader

You would use similar anti-patterns to expose `rrw.Write([]byte) (int, error)` so that it calls through to `c.Response.Out.Write(data []byte) (int, error)`, and `rrw.WriteHeader(int) error` so that it calls `c.Response.WriteHeader(int, string)`. Depending on what is considered appropriate for the framework, either panic on errors or fail silently, since their API doesn't expect `WriteHeader` errors to be handle-able.

### Getting an http.Request from Revel

Unfortunately, the `http.Request` type is a struct, so you can't just simulate it. You basically have two options: reconstruct it using the `net/http` package from all the properties you are able to access, or hope that the `*revel.Request` you have is secretly an `http.Request` under the hood. In the latter case, you can use a type assertion:

```
revelReq, ok := c.Request.In.(*revel.GoRequest)
if !ok {
  // handle this somehow
}
r := revelReq.Original
```